# Alert based on due date

Tags: date-time

I am looking to create an alert to a user based on approaching a due date. example, Mr Jones (the doc owner) will get an alert 30 days before his document needs to be reviewed.

I have looked through the built in features and don see how I can make this happen...any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the enterprise version, you can use information rights management to trigger a workflow that is based on a date column.

Comment: This should be the answer.